# What could two sections in my thesis be named instead of "current functionality" and "proposed functionaliy"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, synonyms

My supervisor does not like names of two chapters in my thesis (for whatever reason). My thesis is focused on output data management from web processing services (just to add some context). These names are:

**1) Current Functionality**

In this chapter I talk about two options that clients can choose from currently.

**2) Proposed Functionality**

Here, I talk about a third, new option. Development of this new option was the main objective of my thesis.

I have been thinking about it for several days now but I can't think of anything better. And since I am not a native speaker, my vocabulary is limited. Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think you should discuss with your supervisor why the names aren't acceptable - we could give you suggestions that they would like even less because we don't understand why your existing choices don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/functionality) and I don't disagree with you.

How about "Current Features" and "Proposed Improvement", or "Currently Available Options" and "Improved Method"?

For #2 perhaps include exactly **what** the improvement is: "Faster Method", "Means to Reduce Errors", "Methodology to Ensure ...".